# Apply a function on a 2D array using a mask and a starting index

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 2D numpy array as follows:

```
x = array([
           [0, 7, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4],
           [9, 5, 1, 3, 5, 4, 8],
           [8, 5, 8, 1, 1, 2, 0],
           [5, 6, 3, 9, 8, 9, 1],
           [2, 9, 4, 6, 7, 6, 0]
          ])
```

I want to apply a function to that array starting at a specific index **and** using a mask.

For example, I want to apply the function `value = randint(250, 255)` starting at position [0,3] using the mask

```
 [
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]
 ]
```

which would give me

```
x = [
     [0, 7, 1, 254, 252, 253, 4],
     [9, 5, 1, 251, 5,   251, 8],
     [8, 5, 8, 255, 1,   252, 0],
     [5, 6, 3, 250, 8,   250, 1],
     [2, 9, 4, 252, 254, 255, 0]
    ]
```

P.S. Array x is randomly generated and can be `[30, 15]`, `[60, 30]` or `[120, 60]`. The starting index will also be randomly selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky, but you can extend the mask to full size, then use a flattened view to assign the changed values:

```
mask = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1]
                 ])

# extended mask
m = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool)
m[0:0+mask.shape[0], 3:3+mask.shape[1]] |= mask==1

# assign new values using a flattened view
x.ravel()[m.ravel()] = np.random.randint(250, 255, size=m.sum())
```

output:

```
array([[  0,   7,   1, 253, 250, 252,   4],
       [  9,   5,   1, 252,   5, 254,   8],
       [  8,   5,   8, 254,   1, 254,   0],
       [  5,   6,   3, 254,   8, 252,   1],
       [  2,   9,   4, 252, 254, 253,   0]])
```

intermediate `m`:

```
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. I only changed the line
`m[0:0+mask.shape[0], 3:3+mask.shape[1]] |= mask==1` to use the random location like so
`m[random_location[0]:random_location[0]+mask.shape[0], random_location[1]:random_location[1]+mask.shape[1]] |= mask==1`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use a full mask?

```
from random import randint

x = [
  [0, 7, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4],
  [9, 5, 1, 3, 5, 4, 8],
  [8, 5, 8, 1, 1, 2, 0],
  [5, 6, 3, 9, 8, 9, 1],
  [2, 9, 4, 6, 7, 6, 0]
]

mask = [
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]

for i,row in enumerate(x):
  for j,_ in enumerate(row):
    if mask[i][j]:
      x[i][j] = randint(250,255)
print(x)
```

Comment: The array is randomly generated and can be  `[30, 15]`, `[60, 30]`, or `[120, 60]`. That's quite big and the starting location is also randomly selected

Comment: if the array is randomly selected, how do you know where to put the mask?

Comment: The array is generated and then a random location is selected say [1, 5] then the top left of the mask should start at [1, 5]

Comment: That seems like something that is straight forward to generate. Start out with an array the same size as x, initialized to 0 or False, and then modify it to input the mask you want. You can specify the offsets using the starting point